# Get all windows xp and server 2003 machines code fail

Tags: powershell

I need to find in my organization all the old machines like winxp or server 2003,win98
 i ran this code but i dont get any error neither a result

```
get-adcomputer -filter * -properties name,operatingsystem | where-object {($_.operatingsystem -like "windows xp") -and ($_.operatingsystem -like "windows server 2003") -and ($_.operating system -like "windows 98")}
```

Comment: you are using `-and` ... and that means you are tyring to match ALL the tests. [*grin*] try using `-or` instead.

Comment: great.tnx guys!

Comment: its odd but the script only finds windows server 2003, even if i look for win10 hell find only server 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as mentioned in the comments, you should use the logical operator OR. It is one or the other ... not all together.

Also, because using like, try to use a smaller keywords that would match like XP for Windows XP, 2003 for Windows Server 2003 and etc.

```
get-adcomputer -filter "operatingsystem -like '*xp*' -or operatingsystem -like '*2003*' -or operatingsystem -like '*98*'" -properties operatingsystem
```

What I would do personally is to export everything into CSV, put it into excel with table and filters and review in details. Sometimes the names look a bit strange (i.e. windows server 2008 has a strange symbol included like trademark, or something) and you will get more holistic view on the OS names

you may also do something like this to identify numbers:

`get-adcomputer -filter * -properties operatingsystem | Group-Object -Property operatingsystem`

Comment: could i talk you into switching from the `{}` scriptblock filter style to the - as documented - _string_ filter style? it always bugs me to see that used ... and it is fragile, so it is more likely to glitch than the correct string filter.